# glibc-2.14 when 'make install' failed whit 2 error

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, glibc

> /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 include/limits.h /usr/local/glibc-2.14/include/limits.h
>
> /usr/bin/install: `include/limits.h' and` /usr/local/glibc-2.14/include/limits.h' are the same file
>
> make[1]: *** [/usr/local/glibc-2.14/include/limits.h] Error 1
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/glibc-2.14'
>
> make:  ***[install] Error 2

install glibc-2.14, when i enter 'make install' it show this 2 error

someone help me

Thanks

Comment: Seems a glibc is already on the system.  Possibly conflict with this source code version.

Comment: Actually there should be no conflict, i.e. the new /usr/local/glibc-2.14//* is a hidden location. You could try `make install -k -i` ... http://linux.die.net/man/1/make

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're trying to install glibc into the same place you built it ?  simple answer: don't do that.

if that isn't what you're doing, please describe the exact `./configure` and `make` and `make install` commands you're using.

Answer (score 0):

use difference folder for the build and prefix, like:

- the build folder path is ~/glibc-2.14/build
- and the prefix folder path is /opt/glibc-2.14

it will solve this